# How to add images to Unite Gallery with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using Unite Gallery plugin to show a gallery of images which already contains images at the loading of my page. But I need to let the user add more images to the gallery by himself by clicking a button and importing his file. This part is OK, each user can import images on my server, and when he reloads the page, his images are well displayed on my Unite Gallery.
But if he doesn't reload the page, the images aren't displayed in the gallery.
I need a way to reload the gallery without reloading my whole page.

I tried with the reloadGallery function but even if it does reload the gallery, my new image isn't shown.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let gallery = $('#gallery').unitegallery();
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(result) {
            $("#gallery").append('<img alt="" src="../../uploads/images-menu/' + result["photoName"] + '" data-image="../../uploads/images-menu/' + result["photoName"] + '">');
            gallery.reloadGallery();
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the plugin website : http://unitegallery.net/

Comment: can you give reference to reloadGallery function

Comment: I saw it here, at the end of the thread:
https://github.com/vvvmax/unitegallery/issues/22

I don't know if it helps, i didn't find this function on the official documentation, even if it does reload the gallery...